# Is it ever possible to combine a cookie consent notice with HTML output caching?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, caching, cookies, kentico

This is a bit of a conceptual question but hopefully allowed here because there may be a technique to solve the challenge that I'm unware of.

I have an ASP.NET-driven web application for which I want to use HTML output caching to improve performance. I also need to add a cookie consent notice which must be available to all visitors so of course I cannot rely on Javascript. Therefore the choice of whether or not to display this notice depends on code logic server side based on a cookie which is persisting the visitor's consent. But of course this code will not run if I'm serving up a cached page.

So my question is: does the EU requirement for a cookie consent notice mean that we developers cannot use any caching mechanism which works with full HTML output?

My specific use case is an instance of Kentico CMS which has its own output caching mechanism with various variables to differentiate cached pages, one being user. But obviously I don't want to cache a version of every page for every possible visitor because that would get out of hand. So are there any solutions to this conundrum that I'm unware of?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe look into Russian Doll Caching, I'm not 100% sure if it'll work for this but it involves creating multiple caches and stitching them together so you only update the cache of what's changed.

Something similar concept could work for you. cache the output of chunks separately and then display them based on cookie value.

The problem I'm seeing is that without at least some javascript you're forced into performing a form load to update the cookie value.

Answer (score 0):

Well, when you use full output caching and you cannot use Javascript the only **ugly solution** comes to my mind is to use IFRAME that serves only cookie law consent. Page referenced with IFRAME will not be cached so you can decide if you serve empty content or cookie law consent.

iframe would be defined as follows:

```
<iframe src="https://[your_cookie_law_consent_page]" style="position: absolute;z-index: 99999;bottom: 0px;width: 100%;height: 70px;overflow: hidden;background-color: transparent;border: none;" allowtransparency="true" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

[your_cookie_law_consent_page] = page or handler where you render cookie law consent or empty transparent content/no content. I would use ashx handler or You can use new kentico page that will not be cached with cookie law consent webpart that has correctly set "Visible" condition.

This approach has some serious problems like:

- Transparent iframe will eat all clicks in zone where he is
- I'm not sure about browser compatibility, but it wouldn't count with wide support of this approach without testing

**So if you are going to use this solution, you have to place it carefully, possibly use it with NOSCRIPT tag...**

But for this case i still **recommend JavaScript**...

Answer (score 0):

Have the bar visible by default, and hidden in JS, rather than invisible by default and shown by JS.

If there are legitimate users with javascript disabled for whatever reason, they can still see the message, but cannot hide it.